# How To Rebind to Server in GO

Tags: sql-server, http, go-html-template

I am writing a Go Web App that displays data to a webpage. The database is in Microsoft SQL Server 2008. When running the program, the URL is properly handled in the main function to a function WebHandler() using ListenAndServe on Port 8080, but as soon as I connect to the SQL database, the web server connection is lost.
WebHandler() connects to the sql database, fills struct values with sql results, and loads the struct into an html/template to fill out a table accordingly.
I am using the github.com/LukeMauldin/lodbc" and "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx" packages to get sql results and they display fine.  How do I reestablish the webservice in the WebHandler Function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I was trying to connect to the sql database on every page. The key is to connect only once and defer the close